# Scala. How to take the count of array of first array using scala

Tags: scala

I have a file with words separated by * and lines separated by ~, I would like to count the specific word how many times it is appeared in the file.

For eg.

Input File:

```
AB*xyz*1234~
CD*mny*769~
MN*bvd*2345~
AB*zar*987~
```

Code:

```
for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines()) {
      array = line.split("\\~")

for (row <- array ){
      val splittedRow=row.split("\\*")
      val cnt = splittedRow(0).contains("AB").count()
```

Here i am facing the issue in, how many times the word AB is present. Can you please help me how to get the count of specific words from an array. I am not able to use the keyword .count.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small function for your case:

```
def count(term:String,file:File): Int = {
    Source.fromFile(file, "UTF-8").getLines().foldRight(0)((line, count) => {
        count + line.split("\\*").filter(_.contentEquals(term)).length
    })
}

println(count("AB",PATH_TO_INPUT)) // result is 2
```

all lines will check if there is your delimitter, filter the list of words  to the term and add the length of remaining words to the current count value.

[this](https://commitlogs.com/2016/09/10/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright/) helps me to understand fold methods

I hope that answer your question

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(_.split("\\*")).count(i => i.headOption.exists(_.contains("AB")))
```

`count` by `contains` function with first element and use `Option` to handle `None`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! with this i am getting the count from all the lines where ever it is matching. but i want only first word from all lines.

Comment: if i need to match only second word from all lines what should i use kindly help

Comment: such as: `arr.lift(1).exists(_.contains("AB"))`

Comment: Thanks For Reply Result is coming true
false
false
false i need get count only

Comment: you should combine with `count` such as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> the issue in, how many times the word AB is present. Can you please help me how to get the count of specific words from an array

You can read the file using `Source` api and then *store the separated words in a list*.

```
val resultArray = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().flatMap(line => line.replace("~", "").split("\\*")).toList
```

You can count the number of repeatition of each words by call *count function* as

```
println(resultArray.count(_ == "AB"))   //will print 2
println(resultArray.count(_ == "CD"))   //will print 1
println(resultArray.count(_ == "xyz"))  //will print 1
```

I hope the answer is helpful